# Add values to an json element

Tags: gson

I have a file name test.json

```
{ "aaData": 
  [
   {
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "4",
    "grade": "X"
   },
   {
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "C"
   }
  ]
}
```

I read this file and i would like to get this

```
{ "sEcho":"1",
  "iTotalRecords":97,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords":9,
  "aaData": 
  [
   {
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "4",
    "grade": "X"
   },
   {
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "C"
   }
  ]
}
```

my code to read and build

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
FileReader fr = new FileReader("web.json");
JsonElement element = parser.parse(fr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("\"sEcho\":\"1\",");
sb.append("\"iTotalRecords\":\"97\",");
sb.append("\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":\"9\",");

Gson gson = new Gson();   
JsonElement data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), JsonElement.class);
data.getAsJsonArray().add(element);
```

From the line fromJSon,  i get

com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

My string is not ok?

I tried

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(sb.toString()));
reader.setLenient(true);
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class);
element.getAsJsonArray().add(data);
```

I get This is not a JSON Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string ends up as

```
"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":"97","iTotalDisplayRecords":"9",
```

This is not valid JSON. For it to be valid JSON, it would need to be inside of { }

However, my recommendation would be to avoid doing json building yourself.

Instead of pragmatically editing a json string, which is usually tricky, I would suggest creating a java class that matches the input format, and a java class that matches the output format.

Create an instance of the input class with:

```
InputClass i = gson.fromJson(inputString, InputClass.class)
```

Then create a instance of your output class normally.

```
OutputClass o = new OutputClass();
o.sEcho = 1;
o.iTotalRecords= 97;
o.iTotalDisplayRecords = 9;
o.aaData = i;
```

Finally render your output back to json

```
String result = gson.toJson(o);
```

This may seem longer than just appending to a string, but its guaranteed to produce a valid JSON string, and is better at handling changes. Your output is also guaranteed to always be in the same format. If the input file changed format, your output may not have all values set correctly, but at least the structure will be there which will help prevent breaking changes in whatever consumes your output.